Creates new file when run as root instead of opening it
I cannot edit files when VIM is run as root. Why?
Here's a file which contains 123 on the first line and nothing else:
File opened as root:

Typed in listen as root:

I am confident that VIM has not changed the working directory because I did open the file with autocompletion and :!pwd does show the same directory. Opening the file with an absolute path does not make a difference.

Absolute path to the file: /home/user0011/txt.txt
Command: vim ./txt.txt
Platform: Linux.
Terminal: vt220
Version: VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled May 04 2023 10:24:44)

Could you share the path of the file you try to open and the command you use to do so? Could you tell us the OS (Windows, Linux, macOS) that you are using? It will help us to reproduce the problem?

Thank you for contributing. I've updated the question.

Your terminal looks strange, what is it? What is $TERM set to? What is the Vim version? Have you tried vim --clean?

I can narrow it down to using VIM while connected to a KVM guest through "virsh".

And what is your terminal? and $TERM? and what about vim --clean?

vim --clean has not resolved the problem.

I don’t recommend running. Im as root, generally. Try sudoedit/sudo -e instead? There’s also some probable TERM problems; does the virtual instance have the right terminfo entries/is the TERM variable set correctly?
